# Changing a form redirect value, when you can't edit the form HTML itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a site builder tilda.cc.

They don't let you edit the HTML of their own elements.

But you can add an HTML block, where JS is allowed.

What I'm trying to do, is figure out, how can I add one of the form input values, to the redirect URL as a GET element.

For example:

1. User enters a form field.
2. On clicking to another form field, the code should add to the redirect URL the value that the user just entered.

For example, if user entered email@domain.com, the JS code would add it as a GET parameter to the redirect link.

Redirect.com/success?email=email@domain.com

Is it even possible to do it like this?

This is the basic code, how the form looks like:

```
<form action method="POST" data-success-url="redirect.com/success">
    <input type="text" name="Email">
</form>
```

I can get the email to be displayed as an alert:

```
<script>
$('form').change(function() {
  alert('email input value: ' + 
      $(this).find('input[name=Email]').val());
});
</script>
```

But how would I actually go about adding it to the "data-success-url"?

Comment: You could potentially use JS to change the `form` to a GET request: `$('form').prop('action', 'GET')`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the form data are stored in the page builder database via POST request, so I don't think that's a solutin.

Comment: So is the form submit using AJAX?